# Processing a json parsing in separate java file in android

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I have a main_activity class the extends from Activity class. I need to perform a json parsing in another java file called json_parsing.java .I am planning to declare a method in json parsing class and create  object in main_activity class.
My doubt is

1) Should i add the json parsing class in android manifest  ? If so, How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Should i add the json parsing class in android manifest ? If so, How can i do it?

No you don't have to do that. Unless it extends from `Activity` or `Service` or `Application`, which I doubt.

If you use Android Studio and have a class that should be declared in the manifest, but isn't, when you try to use that class, an error will occur and Android Studio will tell you to add it to the manifest, so you know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it to the manifest. Adding is only needed when `Activity`, `Service` or `Application` is extended

You can create the json_parsing.class and add a public parse mehtod. Then in the main_activity you instantiate a new json_parsing() and use the public methode.

JSON_PARSING

```
class json_parsing {
.
public void parseJson() {
  // do your stuff
}
.
}
```

MAIN_ACTIVITY

```
main_activity
{
.
json_parsing parsing = new json_parsing();
parsing.parseJson();
.
}
```

Comment: *You dont nee to add it to the manifest if you use it only when Activity, Service or Application is extended* that doesn't really make sense, what do you mean to say?

Comment: oeps. maybe this is better

Answer (score 0):

If your JsonParsing class doesn't extend an `Activity` too or isn't a `Service` you don't need to declare it in the manifest.

By the way I want only to underline some things:

- create the model in another class
- use capitalized letters to start class names

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to add each java file or class in Manifest file. Only the components of Android are added to the Manifest file.

I advice you to create a separate package like "Utils", and create a Class `JSONParser.java`

**You can see this tutorial also**

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

We dont need to add Java (Model class) which we create as support classes for our activity in Manifest file. Only we need to add activity, services or receivers in Manifest file